# Using mechanize with a hidden log-in page

Tags: python, mechanize, scraper

I want to write a scraper to pull pdfs from a [database of police reports](http://www.policereports.us/Monthly/index.php), but I've run into a snag. When I click the page's "Log In" button, it doesn't bring up a separate URL, it just loads the log-in page asynchronously. I'm not sure how it does this - I've watched the Net tab in my console but the page doesn't seem to be making any XHR requests.

I was planning to write my scraper in Python, so I'd like to use the mechanize library to log in and crawl through the pdfs. But before I can do any of that, I've got to find that pesky log-in page!

Comment: I'm not sure it's loading asynchronously, it looks like it's just unhidden with JQuery.

Comment: @fdsa That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web page is doing a lot of Ajax type of activity, then you really can't just use an HTML parser - you also need a Javascript interpreter.

You'll likely be forced to use something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).